# How to open db.sqlite3 in Visual studio for django project

Tags: python, database, visual-studio

I want to use the db.sql 3 but when I open it is not reading the file. Moreover, I also downloaded SQLite extension but when I again click on db.SQLite 3 is nothing showing there. So please help me regarding this.

Comment: you can use [https://inloop.github.io/sqlite-viewer/](view)

Answer (score 2):

1. First download/install the SQLite extension in VS Code
2. open command palette and type: >SQLite Open Database
3. choose file
4. now you should see the DB at the bottom of the explorer

Another option is to use [DB Browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/)

Answer (score 0):

download extension called sqlite viewer on your vs code